# How to add a timer to individual items in a list in python?

Tags: python, list, timer

I am writing a program where I have 2 lists. When a certain condition is met, I would like to move an item from "active list" to an "inactive list". Then, I would like to set a timer for the item that moved to inactive list for 4 hours. Once time expires, I would like to move the item back to the active list.

I could have a number of items go to the inactive list, and each item would need its own 4hour timer.

Some simple code:

```
games_active = []
games_not_active = []

while True:
    for x in games_active:
        game = games_active.pop()
        try:
            bot.click_autos()
            sleep(random.uniform(4.8, 5.9))
        except TypeError:
            games_not_active.append(game)
            error += 1
```

I cant think of any solution that would do what i need. Any suggestions where to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
My idea...

* Create a dictionary of all of your games
* For each game - capture the time before it switches back to active (for active games, set to 0)
* Decrement this time in your loop
* Generate your list on the fly whenever you need it.

So its something like this...

games = dict()
games['game1'] = dict()
games['game1']['timetoActive'] = 0
games['game1']['status'] = 'active'
....

while True:

for game in games:
    if game['timetoActive'] > 0:
       game['timetoActive'] = game['timetoActive'] - 1
       # Decrease the time

    else:
      games['game1']['status'] = 'inactive'

.....

Then if you need to get all of the active games you could do something like

games = [game for game in games if game['Status'] = 'Active']
```

Comment: This approach seems interesting. I think I would need to modify to capture the time when it moves to inactive, then compare to current time and if its greater than 4 hours move to active. Thank you for the idea though!

Comment: Sounds good - feel free to accept the answer if this meets your needs